# Questions about kotlin-compiler in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, build

When I was building a project, I was prompted to report the following error
I'm using a MAC and this question confuses me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fN8lW.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSjkM.png)

I tried reinstalling kotlin but it doesn't work

```js
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':IAP:compileReleaseKotlin'.
> java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /Users/jianpingliang/MyApplication/build/kotlin/sessions/kotlin-compiler-8513955117543825844.salive

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':Only:compileReleaseKotlin'.
> java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /Users/jianpingliang/MyApplication/build/kotlin/sessions/kotlin-compiler-4081466192223101837.salive

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/8.0-milestone-3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 779ms
60 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 56 up-to-date
```

Comment: That picture is not really helpful, if you clicked on the other error indications, such as ":IAP:compileReleaseKotlin" or even the top "Build MyApplication: failed" you probably would get a full error stacktrace, which would help a lot

Comment: And now if you could paste the whole stacktrace instead of just adding a picture

Comment: Should it be like this (red text)? Still need all the content, thanks  JustSightseeing

Comment: It is way better now, thank you.
As suggested by the error message try running "./gradlew build --warning-mode all", to see what gradle features are incompatible with your gradle version

Comment: Thanks,JustSightseeing
 I'm trying to find the problem using this method Thanks again